# flutter - FCM notification appears twice when app is in background

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am working on firebase messaging for handling background message with FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin but I received two notification when I do this. I received 1 notification is from FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin and other one is from system notification. I need to use FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notification because I need to do some customization, how do I disable system default notification?

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await init();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  await setupFlutterNotifications();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await setupFlutterNotifications();
  print('Application background message: $message');
  final title = message.notification!.title;
  final body = message.notification!.body;
  await notificationService.notification(message);
}
```

```
Future<void> notification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification!;
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notification.hashCode,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      const NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'channel id',
          'your channel name',
          channelDescription: 'your channel description',
          icon: 'launch_background',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

I am using laravel-notification-channels/fcm for my fcm notification. My solution for my issue is to comment out fcm setNotification function. Refer to my code below are example.

```
    public function toFcm($notifiable)
    {
        return FcmMessage::create()
            ->setData([
                'title' => json_encode($this->newMessage['title']),
                'body' => json_encode($this->newMessage['body']),
            ])
            // ->setNotification(\NotificationChannels\Fcm\Resources\Notification::create()
            //     ->setTitle($this->newMessage['title'])
            //     ->setBody($this->newMessage['body'])
            //     // ->setImage($this->newMessage['user']['image'])
            // )
            ->setAndroid(
                AndroidConfig::create()
                    ->setFcmOptions(AndroidFcmOptions::create()->setAnalyticsLabel('analytics'))
                    ->setPriority(AndroidMessagePriority::HIGH())
                    // ->setNotification(AndroidNotification::create()->setChannelId('high_importance_channel'))
            )->setApns(
                ApnsConfig::create()
                    ->setFcmOptions(ApnsFcmOptions::create()->setAnalyticsLabel('analytics_ios'))
            );
    }
```

Comment: You do not need to show a notification `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage` handler. Firebase does it automatically.

Comment: but i want to do customization for the notification like grouping, change icon and handle onclick. Do you know how to customize firebase notification?

Comment: It depends on your server environment and provider. If you're using FCM check out [API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages)
If you're using OneSignal check out [link](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/mobile-push-notifications-guide)

Comment: I am in the same situation now. Please let me know, if you found some solution. @noahark

Comment: @RudrakshyaBarman yes I have found a solution. Basically it happened twice because one if fcm push notification and another one is flutterlocalnotification. If you want to use flutterlocalnotification then you will need to send fcm without push notifcation.

Comment: @noahark Can you please give some code example? Send FCM without push notification: is it kind of this?
'to' => '/topics/'. $topic,
            'notification' => [
                'title' => $title,
                'body' => $body,
            ],
            "data" => [
                "key1" => $title,
                "key2" => $body
            ],

is it about remove 

'notification' => [
                'title' => $title,
                'body' => $body,
            ], part?

Comment: @RudrakshyaBarman i have added my solution on the page. Hope it help.

Comment: However, please note that if we send FCM without a push notification, your app won't receive any notifications while it's in idle mode. This means users might miss important updates or messages if they're not actively using the app at the time.